# How to make bulb menu?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to develop about bulb menu in the VSCode extension.

How to open the bulb menu. I can't find the name of the bulb menu.
What is actually a name?

It is hard to find a name though I am not an English speaker.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The items in the “bulb menu” are called Code Actions or Quick Fixes (see [this documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_code-action)).

> A code action represents a change that can be performed in code, e.g. to fix a problem or to refactor code.

The VSCode extension API docs provide more context on how extensions can provide Code Actions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CodeAction). A Code Action can provide a [WorkspaceEdit](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceEdit) to perform (to amend the text the user entered, for example), or it can provide a [Command](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#Command) to run for more complex actions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/9b8701dceac5fab83345356743170bca609c87f9/code-actions-sample
Your word "Code Actions" helps me to find the official sample.